# Nim: Parallel loop with mutating state

Tags: concurrency, pass-by-reference, nim-lang

I'm new to the [Nim](https://nim-lang.org) language. I wanted to learn it by implementing a simple Genetic Algorithm to evolve strings (array of integers atm) by distributing the work to the CPU cores:

https://github.com/peheje/nim_genetic

I have successfully parallelized the creation of the "Agents", but cannot do it to call a function "life" that must mutate the passed in state:

```
...

type
Agent* = ref object
    data*: seq[int]
    fitness*: float

...
var pool: seq[Agent] = newAgentsParallel(POPULATION_SIZE)
# Run generations
for gen in 0..<N_GENERATIONS:
    let wheel = createWheel(pool)
    let partitions: seq[seq[Agent]] = partition(pool, N_THREADS)
    parallel:
        for part in partitions:
            echo "spawning"
            spawn life(part, pool, wheel)
    pool = createPool(pool, wheel)
...
proc life(part: seq[Agent], pool: seq[Agent], wheel: seq[float]) =
for a in part:
    if random(1.0) < CROSSOVER_PROP:
        a.crossover(pool, wheel)
    if random(1.0) < MUTATE_PROP:
        a.mutate()
    a.calcFitness()
echo "life done"
```

CPU is bound at 100 % and it seems like Nim is copying the data to "life" as the RAM usage skyrockets after "spawning". In the Nim manual it says about the parallel block:

> "Every other complex location loc that is used in a spawned proc
>   (spawn f(loc)) has to be immutable for the duration of the parallel
>   section. This is called the immutability check. Currently it is not
>   specified what exactly "complex location" means. We need to make this
>   an optimization!"

And I'm very much using it as mutable state, so maybe that is why Nim is copying the data? How can I get around passing pointers only? A few points:

- I guess I could avoid mutating, instead returning new instances that are modified, but I still need to pass in the pool and wheel to **read from**.
- If the parallel: statement is not possible to use, how would I implement it using threads?
- Is random() threadsafe? How else?
- Anything else I could do different? E.g. easier unwrapping of the FlowVar?

Coming from Kotlin with Java8 Streams I feel really spoiled.

Comment: Update: by inspecting the C or CPP code generated I can see the wrapper for the life function deepCopies the arguments "pool", "wheel" and "part". Which I do not want. Snippet: N_NIMCALL(void, lifeWrapper_3iD9bvP7DZjU3JFcD7cH26g_2)(void* thread, void* args) {
 ... genericSeqDeepCopy((&colontmp_), (*((tyObject_Env_nim_geneticdotnim__KeiV9a9cjzNnodvQd0yRpBPA*) (args))).part0, (&NTI_827srMGabItaeI6XT9cYzxA_));